# Check if in a particular category, then add a class to post images in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, class, post

*I'm trying to get a gallery setup on a page, along with a lightbox effect, which I will achieve with jQuery.*

I need to add a class to each image, so that jQuery can target this class and do its thing - unfortunately, I also need this effect to only apply to images within a given category - so adding the class with jQuery won't do.

Here is my code so far (it doesn't work):

```
if ( in_category( 'gallery' )) {
/** * Attach a class to linked images' parent anchors * e.g. a img => a.img img */

function give_linked_images_class($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){ $classes = 'gallery_img gllry'; // separated by spaces, e.g. 'img image-link'  

// check if there are already classes assigned to the anchor

if ( preg_match('/<a.*? class=".*?">/', $html) ) { $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*? class=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $html); } else { $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" >', $html); } return $html; } add_filter('image_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_class',10,8);
```

I put it in my theme's functions.php, and nada, zilch. It should be targeting img tags within a tags, within the category 'gallery', no?

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: You want this on any image on your site or only to content specific images?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you have a post in a particular category, it may have the classes `.category-ID`  or `.category-name` applied to it. You just need to add your styling yo your style.css file.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

Comment: Wordpress doesn't add any classes to it at all, except for very generic "right" "centered" or "left" to position the element. CSS styling won't help with jQuery selection though...